# Exit Fullscreen QMediaPlayer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmediaplayer

My question is how do I exit full screen. I have made a program that is set up as such:

```
    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def UI:
            some random ui stuff
            self.fullscreenbutton.clicked.connect(self.fullscreen)
        def vid(self):
            self.Video_Player = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget(self.centralWidget)
            self.Video_Player.setObjectName("videoPlayer")
            self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.Video_Player)
            self.Video_Player.show()
            self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
            self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.filePath)))
            self.player.setVideoOutput(self.Video_Player)
            self.player.play()
        def fullscreen(self):
            self.Video_Player.setFullscreen(True)
```

anyway, How would I use a keypress event to exit full screen. I know how to do a keypress event however because of the way the code is set up I can't seem to get them working (hence the very rough layout given above).

I'm running windows 7, python 3.5, PyQt5.

P.S. Sorry for not giving full code out, This is for a school assignment and if the code is found online it could get difficult proving it is all mine.

Comment: Most of the code you've shown has no relevance to the problem you are actually trying to solve. Please post a proper [mcve].

Comment: It's not clear if the problem is about the handling of a keypress event (_"because of the way the code is set up I can't seem to get them working"_) or a function to exit fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            self.Video_Widget=Video_Widget_Class()
            self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.Video_Widget) 


class Video_Widget_Class(QVideoWidget):
        def Video_Widget(self):
            self.Video_Player = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget(self.centralWidget)
            self.Video_Player.setObjectName("videoPlayer")
            self.Video_Player.show()

        def keyPressEvent(self, event):
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape and self.isFullScreen():
                self.setFullScreen(False)
                event.accept()
            elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Enter and event.modifiers() & Qt.Key_Alt:
                self.setFullScreen(not self.isFullScreen())
                event.accept()

        def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
            self.setFullScreen(not self.isFullScreen())
            event.accept()
```

This is what I used to solve the problem. There was other stuff under the Ui_MainWindow but this should help out anyone having the same issue.